# Weblogic Persistent File store Directory does not exist

Tags: jms, weblogic

I am having some problem in creating JMS Queue. After creating the JMS Server and module, I created a JMS Queue and Connection factory. When I try to activate changes, I get following exception message in weblogic console.

**The Messaging Kernel 'JMS server name' has not yet been opened.**

I checked the logs of managed server and found the below exception.

**weblogic.messaging.kernel.KernelException: The Messaging Kernel 'JMS server name' has not yet been opened.**

I guess there is some problem with my persistent file store. But I am not able to find that. While starting the managed server, it gave me error that filestore directory does not exist. I created the directory which it was asking, still the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to server log, and see to which directory, persistent file system pointing to. Make sure that directory must exist, or else you can create that manualy.
2. While creating the managed server from console, see on which machine it hosted.
   and make sure persistent directory must exist on that machine.